# T-SQL Query returning different number rows when run immediately after each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Afternoon all

Strange one this. I have written a query which is fairly simple and I had assumed it was working ok. However, when I run the query, one after another, multiple times, I get a different number of rows every time. It is a live database, but apart from me, nobody is using it today. The date range I have set in my parameters is way in the past, so no new\deleted records should affect it. So I'm a little confused as to why sometimes I get more rows, sometimes less rows when I should get back the same rows every time. Copy of the code below

```
DECLARE 
        @From date,
        @To date

SET @From = '01/07/2015'
SET @To = '31/12/2015'

--AS


SELECT DISTINCT
    BR.Branch, 
    DIV.Division,
    BCM.ClientRef@ AS 'Client Reference',
    BPY.PolicyRef@ AS 'Policy Reference',
    AE.Name AS 'Account Executive',
    DIV2.#Name AS 'Account Handler',
    BTX.Dt_raised AS 'Effective Date',
    BTX.Ledger_dt AS 'Ledger Date',
    INS.VTDescription AS 'Insurer',
    BPY.Ptype AS 'Policy Type',
    BTX.Orig_Debt AS 'GWP',
    COALESCE(BTX.Comm_amt, 0) AS 'Commission',
    CASE
        WHEN BTX.Ccode = '7' THEN 0
        ELSE COALESCE(CHG.Orig_Debt, 0)
    END AS 'Fee',
    COALESCE(BTX.Comm_amt, 0) + CASE WHEN BTX.Ccode = '7' THEN 0 ELSE COALESCE(CHG.Orig_Debt, 0) END AS 'Income',
    CASE DATENAME(MONTH, BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'July' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'August' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'September' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'October' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'November' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'December' THEN YEAR(BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'January' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
        WHEN 'February' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
        WHEN 'March' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
        WHEN 'April' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
        WHEN 'May' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
        WHEN 'June' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, BTX.Dt_Raised))
    END AS 'FinYear',
    CASE DATENAME(MONTH, BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'January' THEN 'Ja'
        WHEN 'February' THEN 'Fe'
        WHEN 'March' THEN 'Ma'
        WHEN 'April' THEN 'Ap'
        WHEN 'May' THEN 'My'
        WHEN 'June' THEN 'Ju'
        WHEN 'July' THEN 'Jy'
        WHEN 'August' THEN 'Au'
        WHEN 'September' THEN 'Se'
        WHEN 'October' THEN 'Oc'
        WHEN 'November' THEN 'No'
        WHEN 'December' THEN 'De'
    END AS 'Month Letter',
    DATENAME(MONTH, BTX.Dt_Raised) AS 'MonthName',
    CASE DATENAME(MONTH, BTX.Dt_Raised)
        WHEN 'January' THEN 7
        WHEN 'February' THEN 8
        WHEN 'March' THEN 9
        WHEN 'April' THEN 10
        WHEN 'May' THEN 11
        WHEN 'June' THEN 12
        WHEN 'July' THEN 1
        WHEN 'August' THEN 2
        WHEN 'September' THEN 3
        WHEN 'October' THEN 4
        WHEN 'November' THEN 5
        WHEN 'December' THEN 6
    END AS 'Order',
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BCM.ClientRef@ ORDER BY BCM.ClientRef@)
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'Client Count', 
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BPY.PolicyRef@ ORDER BY BPY.PolicyRef@)
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS 'Policy Count'
FROM icp_yyclient AS BCM 
INNER JOIN icp_brpolicy AS BPY ON BCM.ClientRef@ = BPY.ClientRef@ AND BCM.Branch@ = BPY.Branch@
INNER JOIN icp_brcledger AS BTX ON BPY.PolicyRef@ = BTX.PolicyRef@ AND BPY.Branch@ = BTX.Branch@
LEFT JOIN icp_brcledger AS CHG ON BTX.Chg_ptr = CHG.Suffix AND BTX.PolicyRef@ = CHG.PolicyRef@ AND BTX.Branch@ = CHG.Branch@
LEFT JOIN AccountExecutives AS AE ON BCM.Job1 = AE.Code
LEFT JOIN icp_bredetail AS DIV2 ON BPY.#Exec = DIV2.Code AND BPY.Branch@ = DIV2.Branch@
LEFT JOIN Division_VT AS DIV ON DIV2.Ext_department = DIV.Division
LEFT JOIN Branch_VT AS BR ON DIV.Branch = BR.VTId
LEFT JOIN icp_INSC_VT AS INS ON BPY.Insco_INSC_VTId = INS.VTId

WHERE
    BPY.Branch@ = 0
    AND BTX.Dt_Raised BETWEEN @From AND @To
    AND (BTX.Trantype IN ('New Business') AND BTX.Trantype <> 'Charge')
    AND (BPY.Term_code IS NULL AND BPY.Term_date IS NULL)
ORDER BY BR.Branch, DIV.Division, BCM.ClientRef@
```

Comment: It's difficult to follow all of the logic here. One thing to look at as you try to cut this down to a *reasonable* piece of code to ask help with (that doesn't have tens of columns that are probably *irrelevant* to the problem) are your `ROW_NUMBER()` based queries - are your partitioning and ordering columns sufficient so that they *uniquely* define orderings so that you know that, each time you run the query, the same row numbers are being assigned to the same rows?

Comment: there is no way we can answer this.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Divide and conquer. Strip pieces out until it behaves as you expect, then start adding back in until you isolate the issue. I'd start with dropping all of the `case` expressions. Asides: `(BTX.Trantype IN ('New Business') AND BTX.Trantype <> 'Charge')` is redundant. Using month numbers rather than names should be slightly faster and avoids language dependencies. Using `@` and `#` in column names is a bit peculiar. Since you are alone, you can pop the database into [single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx) to ensure that no other users connect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. Don't want to seem ungrateful but whats the point in putting up code that doesn't reflect what I am doing. No point putting code up that is a cut-down version of what I am using. And to Juan Carlos, whats wrong with my question quality. I've stated what my problem is and the code I am using, what more do you want, a copy of the 15gb database to go with it.

Comment: HABO, I have started to do that, its getting pretty thin on code but still doing it. Will keep you posted.

Comment: As a general comment, the field names are fixed by the software house that provides the data to my client. I have no control over #'s and @'s in fieldnames.

Comment: "whats the point in putting up code that doesn't reflect what I am doing" - the point is that cutting down your problem to the smallest one that still demonstrates the issue is a **useful** skill to have, in and of itself. Because often, by performing that task, you'll suddenly hit a point where the problem goes away when you didn't expect it to. You've gotten yourself much closer to understanding the problem. And it's a task we *can't* do (not without a full copy of your database, but please don't add that to the question :-))

Comment: OK, it appears to the by ROW_NUMBER() lines that are causing the problem, although I'm not sure how. If I just got a 1 or 0 on a line by itself, then I could understand it, but I'm getting a whole row of data. Also weird is that I use those two lines of code in many other pieces of code with no issues. I will keep investigating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how the `ROW_NUMBER()` query can affect the number of results:

```
declare @t table (a int, b int, c int)
insert into @t(a,b,c) values
(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(1,1,2)

select distinct a,c,CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
from @t
```

You'll notice that my `ORDER BY` clause is *insufficient* to know which rows will be assigned which row numbers. Running this query, I usually get:

```
a           c           
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0
1           1           1
1           2           0
```

However, *this* result set is also possible:

```
a           c           
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0
1           2           1
```

And that just depends on which row gets assigned row number 1.

If you want determinism, make sure that you specify enough expressions in your `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` clauses so that you *know* that each row's assigned row number will be uniquely determined.

Comment: Brilliant, I understand now, thanks. What is doing my head in though is if I want a counter for each "client" based on ClientRef@ in my resultset, how do I add more determinism into it as that is the only unique field used to identify the "client". Having said that, I actually think its the CASE that is causing the issue as if I just have the ROW_NUMBER() part of the code by itself, my number of rows stays constant.

Comment: @JulianSlaughter - there isn't a *technical* solution at this point. Sorry to sound harsh, but you've been using `DISTINCT` as a crutch. Rather than exploring your data and understanding *why* you're getting duplicate results, you've ignored the problem. Again, we're unable to help when we're just presented with raw (and vast) queries and do not have access to your tables and data. You need to learn to distil your problems down to their essential parts - and again, this skill can help you to learn to solve (some) problems yourself.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. The data isn't mine, it belongs to my client, who gets it from their software provider. It isn't the best database in the world and the design is poor, so I can only work with what I have. I will look at my code and see if there is a better way around it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing non-deterministic in your query (like GETDATE() etc), so the only way the results would change is if the data is changing.   I know you think it isn't, but until you can PROVE it isn't, you have to assume it is.

If I needed to investigate something like this, I'd start simplifying the query by removing JOINS until I find which table(s) have the data changing, and then focus on what's going on in those tables.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, a potential point of non-determinism is if those `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` within the `ROW_NUMBER()` queries are insufficient to uniquely define the row numbers.

Comment: I see your point, but as far as I can tell the query doesn't JOIN or filter on those results, so the number of rows returned shouldn't vary because of them.

Comment: Ah I see, the DISTINCT could result in different row counts.   Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue and the cause turned out to be the float data type. I had a de facto SELECT DISTINCT in a cte with a UNION that was treating the same rows as duplicates only some of the time. I cast all my float type fields as decimal(25,10) and the results became consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement reveals a smell to this problem:

> It is a *live* database, but apart from me, nobody is using it *today*.

I'd suggest you look into any automated jobs and make some phone calls/emails to verify that claim.

Next, I'd get rid of your "DISTINCT" statement and, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @TabAlleman suggested, break down the query until you identify what table (or tables) have data getting modified.

The commercial-at character at the end of your field names are confusing. Maybe that's something I don't know about. Does it perform some type of functionality or is it just an embellishment at the end of a field name?

Comment: I have run a SQL Profiler, apart from me, nothing else is happening on the system. Why do I need to get rid of my DISTINCT statement. Because of how the data is stored, I have to have the DISTINCT in there, otherwise I get duplicate rows.

Comment: DISTINCT is often used as a crutch to prevent duplicates when Cartesian products should be addressed. There's a good chance that either your query isn't binding to all the proper constraints (LEFT OUTER JOINs are notorious for allowing this) or that the tables are poorly normalized and contain duplicates themselves. If it's a case of the latter, DISTINCT could be overkill - use JOIN on those few tables as inner queries to increase your performance and reduce duplicate counts.

Answer (score 0):

this is non deterministic
your order by is the same as the partition so you are going to get what ever order it chooses
remove the distinct and the count should be the same

```
CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY BCM.ClientRef@ 
                             ORDER BY BCM.ClientRef@ )
```

to find difference you can use except

```
select .... 
except  
select ....
```