# TSQL CTE's (common table expression) bug

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, row-number

I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5520.0 (X64) 
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Description:

1. `[ORC_RESULT]` and `GROUPING_SELECT` are `CTE` table.

I have strange bug with CTE (common table expression).

```
SELECT a.keysbor
--,gs.[rank]
FROM [ORC_RESULT] AS a inner JOIN GROUPING_SELECT AS gs
    ON a.keysbor = gs.keysbor
WHERE gs.[RANK] = 1
ORDER BY a.keysbor
```

result  36 rows (no duplicate rows)

```
SELECT a.keysbor
,gs.[rank]
FROM [ORC_RESULT] AS a inner JOIN GROUPING_SELECT AS gs
    ON a.keysbor = gs.keysbor
WHERE gs.[RANK] = 1 
ORDER BY a.keysbor
```

result 29 rows

Q: Why filter `gs.[RANK] = 1` have applied only when field `gs.[rank]` exists in `SELECT` statement?

```
without gs.[rank]   with gs.[rank]  rank
10072002992443  10072002992443       1
10072002992444  10072002992444       1
10072002992445  10072002992445       1
10072002992446  10072002992446       1
10072002992447  10072002992447       1
10072002992448  10072002992448       1
10072002992449  10072002992449       1
10072002992450  10072002992450       1
10072002992451  10072002992451       1
10072002992452  10072002992452       1
10072002992453  10072002992453       1
10072002992454  10072002992454       1
10072002992455  10072002992455       1
10072002992456  10072002992456       1
10072002992457  10072002992457       1
10072002992458  10072002992458       1
10072002992459  10072002992459       1
10072002992460  10072002992460       1
10072002992461                       2
10072002992462                       2
10072002992463                       2
10072002992464                       2
10072002992465                       2
10072002992466                       2
10072002992467                       2
10072002992736  10072002992736       1
10072002992866  10072002992866       1
10072002992867  10072002992867       1
10072002992868  10072002992868       1
10072002992869  10072002992869       1
10072002992870  10072002992870       1
10072002992871  10072002992871       1
10072002992872  10072002992872       1
10072002992873  10072002992873       1
10072002992874  10072002992874       1
10072002992875  10072002992875       1
```

Comment: If gs.rank exists only when gs.keysbor exists, then you would need to use a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN.  Also, you would have to then account for gs.Rank being null.

So, the question is... what's your data like?

Comment: Sorry, but, I'm not have enough reputaion on stackoverflow to host image/ file

Comment: yes i use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY...order by ) in GROUPING_SELECT cte table

Comment: What CTE does TDOC exist?  both?  Is it possible that the engine isn't erroring on lack of specification and then selecting tdoc values from different CTEs?

Comment: sorry) my full query enough complexity https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1Nigq6ZW

Comment: It's a tad confusing to use the name `RANK` for a column generated by `ROW_NUMBER()` since there's another function that can be used in that same position called `RANK()`. Can't really analyse your whole query but it will come down to your `ORDER BY` clauses (within your window functions) not being *specific* enough so as to *uniquely* define the order of rows within their partitions. As such, a slight change to the query will generate a different plan and different rows will be assigned `1`.

Comment: thx, for comment. This query has specific bissness logic. One things that  i'm not understant why select statement has  Influence on where statement

Comment: Note that your SQL Server is over 5 years old (and out of support). While bugs in queries are more likely than bugs in engines, you may wish to attempt a reproduction on a more recent version regardless (install free edition of SQL Server 2016, restore database). Even restricting yourself to SQL Server 2008, the last SP is SP4, and there have been fixes to `ROW_NUMBER()` bugs (even though those dealt with parallelism, which this query doesn't use).

Comment: Here's an [old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994799/15498) which illustrates a toy example of how an under-constrained `ORDER BY` can affect the number of rows returned.

Comment: thx for comments. I think in my case i'll need intermediate temp/ variable table ;)

Comment: with field in select (29 rows) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1ZGj9TZ-  without (36 rows) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1Nigq6ZW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your [rank] is not calculated in determinate way, i.e.

```
PARTITION BY A.[KEYKRT], A.[VIDSBR],A.[ORC_ID_ED] ORDER BY A.[ORC_ID_ED]
```

does not uniqely determine the order, so depending on plan operators, row_number() can assign 1 to different rows.
I give you one example where the plan is the same, but the order of rows proceeded is different, and with the same input data you'll get 2 different results.
Depending on what columns you put in SELECT, optimizer builds different plan and your RANK is equal to 1 in different rows (corresponding to different keysbor), so when it comes to join on keysbor, different number of rows are returned.
So in both cases the filter rank = 1 is applyed, but 1 is assigned to different rows.

Here is the example:

```
    declare @t table( a int, b int, c int, primary key(c desc, b)); /*run it as it is, then uncomment PK and run again*/
    insert into @t values 
    (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3),
    (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3);

    declare @t1 table( c int);
    insert @t1 values (1);

    with cte as (
    select row_number() over (partition by a, b order by b) as rn,
           a,
           b,
           c
    from @t 
    group by a, b, c
    )

    select *
    from cte c join @t1 t on c.c = t.c
    where rn = 1;
```

As you can see, I always have the same input, but in the first case I don't declare Primary Key and in the second I do.
Rows returned are different, but it does not mean that filter do not work, it just means that in the first case rn = 1 was attributed to 2 rows with c=1, but in the second case rn = 1 have two rows with c=1 and c=3.